# Python 3 MemoryError: Unable to allocate

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация, outofmemoryerror

На py 2 тот же скрипт работает: В системе стоит 16Гб используется 10ГБ.

При запуске скрипта на py 3.8 16Гб расходуются полностью и выдает ошибку:

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 481. MiB for an array with shape
> (12195, 5171) and data type float64

оба python 64-bit
как это можно исправить?

Comment: очень информативно, ну а если хотите исправить, то перепишите код не тяп-ляп, а по нормальному

Comment: это как позвонить доктору и сказать - "доктор, я сегодня не могу на ногу наступить от боли, а вчера все было OK. Как полечить?" :-D

Comment: Попробуем лечить по фотографии... Python 2.x - какой архитектуры 32-bit или 64-bit и тот же вопрос для Python 3.x?

Comment: @MaxU это скорее "вчера покупала по 5, а сегодня такие же по 25" ;D. Оба питона 64-bit

Comment: @Zhihar  Про "по нормальному" для перехода с py 2 на py 3 ничего не нашла.

Comment: @АннаЛебедева, для тех __кого спрашивают__ моя аллегория лучше подходит ;)

Comment: Ответ я написал, но он очень общий (хотя и, надеюсь, полезный). На вопрос о причинах мой ответ не отвечает, без знания конкретики вашего кода диагноз дать невозможно, дело может быть в чём угодно вообще. Могли и внутренности питона поменяться (а там много чего поменялось) и как-то повлиять, а может вы при переводе кода добавили какой-то незаметный баг, всё может быть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без кода советовать что-то сложно, но есть традиционно применяемые методы:

- **Понизить** тип данных, например, вместо `float64` использовать `float32` или даже `float16` (соответственно, понизив требования к памяти в 2 или в 4 раза), но это зависит от того, какая точность вычислений вам нужна. Для каких-то задач точность понижать нельзя, а для каких-то можно, а то и даже лучше результат с пониженной точностью получается (лучше генерализация).
- Использовать **разреженные матрицы** `scipy.sparse` и те методы и библиотеки, которые умеют с ними работать. Если ваши данные по своей природе **разреженные** это может дать экономию памяти на порядок.
- Если речь о машинном обучении, то зачастую бывает не обязательно обучаться сразу на всех данных, можно использовать случайные подмножества фич и случайное же сэмплирование наблюдений, а потом усреднить получающиеся результаты, сделав такие случайные выборки много раз. А бывает и так, что если данных у вас очень много и они сильно однородные, то и обучение всего на 1/10 случайно выбранных данных (через `df.sample`) даёт почти такое же качество, как и обучение на полном наборе данных, при этом обучение происходит гораздо быстрее, и можно успеть ещё и подобрать оптимальные параметры обучения, повысив качество.

Но и это не всё.

- Некоторые библиотеки позволяют мапить массивы на файлы и не держать таким образом массивы в памяти.
- Есть библиотеки, которые умеют сжимать массивы в памяти и при этом довольно прозрачно с ними работать как с обычными массивами.
- Если вы работаете с `Pandas`, то есть такие библиотеки, как `Dask` и `Vaex`, которые имеют практически такой же интерфейс как `Pandas`, но при этом работают с файлами на диске, подтягивая данные в память по мере необходимости и оптимизируя запросы к данным, например, распараллеливая их.

Answer (score 0):

Подход @CrazyElf  дал свои результаты. Понижение до `float32` устранило проблемы с памятью. Также оказалось полезным знать размер датасетов. Это делается через: `df.info(memory_usage='deep')`

Comment: Ну, поля датасета вообще полезно знать, `int` тоже можно понижать и строки можно переводить в категориальные переменные, если их ограниченный набор, в общем много всего есть, нужно конкретный датасет смотреть.

Comment: @CrazyElf Вот в моем случае, как раз не подстроиться детально. Т.к. делаю универсальную модель для очень разных датасетов. Спасибо за детальнейший ответ!